# What are the marathons with the largest number of participants?

Tags: running, marathon, road-running

In my opinion, [this](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/305/which-marathons-to-run) is a great topic but it does not fit on this website.

So I think that an objective criteria to compare marathons could be the number of participants.

> So what are the city marathons with the largest number of participants by continent?

I would like to consider only the marathons available for amateurs (no requirements of qualifying times, only something like a bill of health).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The largest marathons by continent, [as of 2016](http://arrs.net/MaraList/ML_Fin2016.htm), are:

- *North America*: New York City
- *Europe*: Paris
- *Asia*: Tokyo International
- *Africa*: Soweto
- *South America*: Buenos Aires
- *Australia*: Melbourne

(Source: [ARRS](http://arrs.net/MaraList/ML_Fin2016.htm).)

South Africa's Comrades Marathon would be considered, but it is actually an ultramarathon.

South America has a very big Sao Silvestre race in Brazil (New Year's Eve [traditionally has multiple Saint Silvester races worldwide](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/15329/35)) but it's 15km, not a marathon, despite being listed as one in several places.

Comment: In the "interesting side note" department, the largest Japanese marathon used to be in Hawaii. Marathon running is a huge sport in Japan, but until fairly recently the major Japanese marathons (Fukuoka, Osaka, Beppu-Oita, et al) were invitation only and did not have mass-participation entry. Therefore, Japan Air Lines became a sponsor of the Honolulu Marathon, and for a long time the majority of the entrants in Honolulu were Japanese. I don't know if this is still true now that there are some mass-participation marathons in Japan, though.